# Find the closest DOM element to currently ran script

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I'm currently rebuilding a user 'subscribe' form used to be loaded synchronously and `document.write` was used to append everything to the page, but I have to load jQuery async first so I had to stick to DOM manipulation.
What I'm trying to do is append the main element of this form where everything else is nested.
So in my form I create all of nodes using `document.createElement` and then append them with `container.appendChild(content)`

```
<div class="main">
 <!-- form contents -->
</div>
```

Now, I can append everything inside the form to `.main` but how do I append this form in a specific place in the document itself?
For example

```
<body>
  <div class='container'>
    <script src='form_script.js'>
      <!-- div.main to be generated in div.container -->
    </script>
  </div>
</body>
```

How can I select the element that like in function `.closest()` is the DOM node that the script was pasted into?

Comment: If you don't need IE support, then https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/currentScript should be able to get you the reference to the `script` element itself, so you can proceed from there.

Comment: You can also do `document.querySelector('[src="form_script.js"]');` afaik

Comment: Thanks @CBroe the moment you posted this, I figured that I already used this somewhere in my script and `document.currentScript.insertAdjacentElement('beforebegin', content)` works just fine. Much appreciated!